# Generics and Casting

Tags: c#, generics

Why does the following compile?

```
public IList<T> Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{              
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        return (IList<T>)DeserializeBools(xml);

    return null;
}

private static IList<bool> DeserializeBool(string xml) { ... do stuff ... }
```

But this doesn't

```
public MyClass<T> GetFromDb<T>(string id)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        return (MyClass<T>)GetBoolValue(id);  <-- compiler error here

    return null;
}

private static MyClass<bool> GetBoolValue(string id) { ... do stuff ... }
```

Comment: What is the compile error ...

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Cannot cast expression of type 'MyClass<bool>' to type 'MyClass<T>'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason interfaces work is that *any* object *might* implement `IList<T>` (unless it's known to be an instance of a sealed type which doesn't implement it, I guess) - so there's always a *possible* reference type conversion to the interface.

In the latter case, the compiler isn't willing to do that because it doesn't really know that `T` is bool, despite the previous `if` statement, so it doesn't know what conversion to try between `MyClass<T>` and `MyClass<bool>`. The valid conversions to generic types are pretty limited, unfortunately.

You can fix it fairly easily:

```
return (MyClass<T>)(object) GetBoolValue(id);
```

It's ugly, but it should work... and at least in this case it won't be causing any boxing.

Answer (score 0):

C# 4.0 allows declaration of covariance and contravariance on parameterized **interface** and delegate types.

Comment: This isn't trying to use generic variance, and anyway generic variance doesn't apply to value type type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace

`return (MyClass<T>)`

with

```
return (MyClass<bool>)
```

Comment: Then it will fail to convert from `MyClass<bool>` to the `MyClass<T>` required by the return type.